# How to do count down timer for each room in Socket.io, Nodejs, react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io

I am developing an auction website using Nodejs and react and socket.io. So, the bidding starts at a specific time which will be set at the backend this is not the issue. My question is how to show a countdown timer when a user sends a bid every time. The timer should reset when a new bid is sent. Let's say there are 3 users that join the auction. So when the first user sends a bid the timer should start counting. Then if another user sends a bid before the timer reaches 0 then the timer should reset to 60 seconds and the bid will be changed to the current bid and the auction shall continue. If the timer reaches 0 then the auction is ended. The issue comes here, the timer should come from the backend through socket.io since it is required to show the same countdown for every user in the room.

This is the socket io implementation and the countdown is not showing the correct value. sometime it skips 2 seconds and sometimes it displays a repeated value

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  var countdown = 60;

  socket.on("joinAuctionRoom", async ({ user, auctionRoomId }) => {
    socket.join(auctionRoomId);
  });

  socket.on("getTimers", async ({ auctionRoomId }) => {
    var WinnerCountdown = setInterval(function () {
      io.sockets.to(auctionRoomId).emit("countdown", countdown);
      countdown--;
      if (counter === 0) {
        io.sockets.to(auctionRoomId).emit("aucntionDone", "Acution Completed");
        clearInterval(WinnerCountdown);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

  socket.on("sendBid", ({ auctionRoomId, chat, user }) => {
    counter = 60;
    io.sockets.to(auctionRoomId).emit("recieveBid", { chat, counter, user });
  });

  socket.on("leaveAuctionRoom", ({ roomId, user }) => {
    socket.leave(roomId?.toString());
    console.log(`${user.firstName} left room`);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `counter`? A mis-spelled version of `countdown`?

Comment: There is a global variable that I created with the name counter earlier.

Comment: The issue was from the front end. I was sending several unmanaged requests to the socket.io endpoint which caused that endpoint to misbehave. The request was sent when a user open a page using useEffect hook. The useEffect had an incorrect dependency. So I managed to fix the issue by fixing that dependency.

But I have faced another issue when there is multiple auction room. The timer sent to each room skips 2 seconds at a time.